# Reloading a Commons Configuration 2 Spring bean

Tags: spring, apache-commons-config

I've been using the reload feature of Commons Configuration v1 without any extra coding when exposing a Configuration object as a Spring @Bean, because the reload check was performed every time the Configuration was accessed.

I'm now trying to migrate to Commons Configuration v2 and I read that reload is only effective on new Configuration objects created by the builder.

In other words, while in v1 I could do something like

```
@Bean
public Configuration config() {
    ...
    return builder.getConfiguration();
}
```

then inject the configuration with

```
@Autowired Configuration config;
```

and expect it to reload (when needed) on a

```
config.getString("somepath");
```

now I should call

```
builder.getConfiguration()
```

again each time I want a fresh configuration.

So how do I go about it?
Can anything in Spring help me "refresh" a @Bean that has already been injected in many @Controllers? 
It doesn't have to be automatic: I could implement a "reload" button in the admin console to trigger it.

Comment: Look at Spring Cloud Config.  They've implemented reloading there and it works well.  If you dig into how they've integrated with Spring you may be able to re-use it.  About 6 months ago I did a POC where I got it working with JSON we pull from a config server.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but, for the time being, Spring Config seems to be overkill for what I need to do.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I just have to wrap the Configuration in a MyConfiguration class, exposed as a @Bean, with a method that rebuilds the configuration, to be called from a console. Something like:

```
public class MyConfiguration {
    private Configuration configuration;

    ... inject builder somehow here

    public void reload() {
        builder.getReloadingController().checkForReloading(null);
        configuration = builder.getConfiguration();
    }

    public String getString(String key) {
        return configuration.getString(key);
    }

    ... all other delegated methods follow

}
```